# Invalid object name, but object is clearly valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am attempting to run some SQL queries in MS Access, but a certain query is behaving very oddly and is throwing an error which I believe is obscuring the actual problem. Here is the query in question:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "DECLARE @equipID varchar(50) DECLARE d 
CURSOR FOR SELECT equipmentID FROM [EWOM].[dbo].[equipment] OPEN d" 
& _
" FETCH NEXT FROM d INTO @equipID WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN" & 
_
" UPDATE [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment] SET eqNum = 
REPLACE(REPLACE(equipmentID, ' ', ''), '.', '') WHERE equipmentID = 
@equipID" & _
" FETCH NEXT FROM d INTO @equipID End Close d DEALLOCATE d"
```

And this throws the error

> Invalid Object Name 'EWOM.dbo.Equipment'

However, I've used several queries using this exact same object that have worked perfectly fine. Here's an example of a query that is fully operational:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment]" & _
" INSERT INTO [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment] (equipmentID, make, model, 
equipmentName, status)" & _
" SELECT Equipment, Manufacturer, Model, Description, Status" & _
" FROM [Vp].[dbo].[bEMEM]"
```

What baffles me is that the first query I showed works fine in SQL Server Management Studio, but it failed when I transitioned it to Access. Is the true problem coming from a syntax issue with the first query? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code for a working query:

```
Dim Cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command

Set Cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

Cnn.Open "DBName", "username", "password"
objCmd.ActiveConnection = Cnn

objCmd.CommandText = "TRUNCATE TABLE [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment]" & _
" INSERT INTO [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment] (equipmentID, make, model, 
equipmentName, status)" & _
" SELECT Equipment, Manufacturer, Model, Description, Status" & _
" FROM [Vp].[dbo].[bEMEM] WHERE EMGroup = 20"
objCmd.CommandType = adCmdText

Set rst = objCmd.Execute
MsgBox "Update successful."

Cnn.close
Set Cnn = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
```

When the objCmd.commandText is changed to the first query I posted, it fails. All of my other queries work using this method.

Comment: only thing i can think of is the objCmd ConnectionString is not correct, if the table exists

Comment: Why are you using a cursor to update your table? That should be a single update statement instead of doing the updates one agonizingly slow row at a time.

Comment: What is the collation of your database? In your code that you state works you have a capital E but in your code that fails it is e

Comment: You got it, Sean Lange. It was the lowercase e that was throwing everything off. I am a little frustrated that I missed something as simple as that, but I will note that Access VBA automatically made that "e" lowercase, as it likes to format the code for you sometimes. I copied and pasted all this in so I thought this couldn't possibly be an issue, but I forgot about Access VBA's auto-formatting.

Comment: And also, Sean, how would you recommend updating the table? The ID that comes in from the DB's source comes with spaces and periods, and I thought I'd need to loop through and get rid of them with Replace(). Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean Lange pointed out the obvious, I was making a request to [EWOM].[dbo].[equipment] when it should have been [Equipment]. The letter was capitalized when I copied the text over, but Access VBA changed it to lowercase after I pasted it in, which threw me for a loop.

Comment: I wonder if it is intentional that you have [case-sensitive object names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23179/5203) to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this was simple syntax error you really should consider NOT using a cursor for something to simple. This should be a set based approach instead RBAR (row by agonizing row). Your entire cursor logic could simplified to this. You might consider using stored procedures instead of burying all your sql logic in your application. Gives you more control and is a lot easier in nearly every aspect.

```
UPDATE [EWOM].[dbo].[Equipment] SET eqNum = 
REPLACE(REPLACE(equipmentID, ' ', ''), '.', '')
```

Comment: Thanks a bundle, Sean, this code is far more efficient.